# Error with spring-boot-gradle-plugin when building a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm stuck on the online [Spring example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) with the following error message when I run gradlew bootRun:

```
Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0
```

Looking online it seems like the error pops up when sourceCompatibility is not set to 17 in build.gradle, but here is the line in my configuration:

```
sourceCompatibility = '17'
```

I am not behind a firewall or anything that would cause the network connection to not work.